# Why are different eigenvectors linearly independent? Geometric interpretation

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Why are different eigenvectors linearly independent? I don't need the proof, I need an intuitive explanation and geometric interpretation, please!

Comment: It's false that different eigenvectors must be lin. independent: if $v$ is an eigenvector then so is $2v$ and they're lin. dependent.  What you *meant* to ask is why eigenvectors for *different eigenvalues* of a matrix $M$ are lin. independent. Since you want intuition, not a proof, suppose $u$, $v$, and $w$ are lin. dependent eigenvectors in a 2-dimensional subspace, say $w = au + bv$ for nonzero scalars $a$ and $b$. If $Mu = \lambda u$ and $Mv = \mu v$, then $Mw = a\lambda u + b\mu v$.  For this to be $cw = acu + bcv$, we need $c = \lambda$ and $c = \mu$, so $\lambda = \mu$: contradiction.

Comment: Also note that eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue can be linearly independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As KCd commented, you probably meant to ask why eigenvectors with different eigenvalues are linearly independent. The proof is quite simple, and the essence of it makes for the appeal to intuition that you’re looking for. An eigenvector represents a direction in which a linear transformation has a particularly simple effect: all vectors that lie in this direction are uniformly scaled (and/or reversed) by the transformation. If you have two parallel vectors that are scaled by different factors, they can’t be eigenvectors of the transformation—its action in that direction isn’t a uniform scaling. Indeed, it’s not even possible for the scale factors of parallel vectors to be different since that violates linearity of the transformation.